# in the diagram below what are are corresponding angles and alternate interior angles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]I have posted a diagram of a transversal drawn across a pair of parallel lines in the diagram which angles are corresponding and which are alternate interior angles

Comment: $a$ and $c$ are alternate interior angles (as are their supplementary angles), and $b, d$ are alternate exterior angles.

Comment: and which are corresponding angles thanks

Comment: Oh! I overlooked at your question! Sorry. $a,d$ are corresponding, and also $b,c$.

Comment: See first slide [here](https://slideplayer.com/slide/15852091/).

Comment: Thanks that was helpful